# How to deserialize Json with nested lists

Tags: c#, json, json-deserialization

It's not my first time deserializing Json into c# classes but I am having some trouble when these Json have nested  lists. Here is the returned Json of a list of workOrders:

```
[
  {
    "_id": "5cacdda0b4e6d128a61187ca",
    "taskInstance": [
      {
        "_id": "5cacdda0b4e6d128a61187cc"
      }
    ],
    "isRunning": false
  },
  {
    "_id": "5cacebb0b4e6d128a61187d1",
    "taskInstance": [
      {
        "_id": "5cacebb0b4e6d128a61187d3"
      }
    ],
    "isRunning": false
  }
]
```

and here the C# classes:
WorkOrder

```
public class WorkOrder{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public List<TaskInstance> TaskInstances { get; set; }
    public string IsRunning { get; set; }
}
```

and TaskInstance

```
public class TaskInstance{
    public string Id { get; set; }
}
```

And here is the code that I'm using to check the result:

```
JObject jsonResponse = JObject.Parse(data["data"].ToString());
string workOrderJson = jsonResponse["workOrderInstances"].ToString();
List<WorkOrder> wos = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<WorkOrder>>(workOrderJson);

foreach (WorkOrder wo in wos){
    Debug.Log("WO _id: " + wo.Id);
    Debug.Log("wo.TaskInstances: "+ wo.TaskInstances);
    Debug.Log("WO isRunning: " + wo.IsRunning);
}
```

And while I'm seeing the correct values for WO._id and WO.isRunning wo.TaskInstances seems to be returning null or at leat throws a null reference exception whenever I try to access it.

I've searched other topics before but none of the solutions seem to work. I'm not sure what I am missing. Thank you for your help.

Disclaimer:
the raw **data** in *JObject.Parse(data["data"]* looks like this:

```
{
  "data": {
    "workOrderInstances": [
      {
        "_id": "5cacdda0b4e6d128a61187ca",
        "taskInstance": [
          {
            "_id": "5cacdda0b4e6d128a61187cc"
          }
        ],
        "isRunning": false
      },
      ...
     ]
  }
}
```

Comment: `taskInstance` != `TaskInstances`. You have an extraneous "s" somewhere.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean @CodeCaster

Comment: there is a problem with your model check my answer @jrua

Comment: he means you are trying to deserialize a member named `taskInstance` into a property named `TaskInstanceS` (notice the S)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this model:

Because the problem with your model is:
JSON property name and model property name is not the same in your code.

So whenever you need your own custom name in property use
       `[JsonProperty("JsonPropertyName")]`

```
 public partial class Root
    {
        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("taskInstance")]
        public TaskInstance[] TaskInstances { get; set; }

        [JsonProperty("isRunning")]
        public bool IsRunning { get; set; }
    }

    public partial class TaskInstance
    {
        [JsonProperty("_id")]
        public string Id { get; set; }
    }
```

Let me know if it works for you.

Comment: This worked! Thank you! It never returned erros due to JsonProperty so I assumed I didn't need them. It seems that it couldn't find the properties correctly.